# Is it possible to get priviously visited controller or action id in yii2 PHP framework

Tags: php, yii2

It is possible to get current to controller and action id in`yii2`
 but I can't get previously visited `controller` or `action id`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: use `yii\helpers\Url::previous()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From You guide  can use yii\helpers\Url remember function and get this with previous function

> ```
> use yii\helpers\Url;
>
> // Remember current URL 
> Url::remember();
>
> // Remember URL specified. See Url::to() for argument format.
> Url::remember(['product/view', 'id' => 42]);
>
> // Remember URL specified with a name given
> Url::remember(['product/view', 'id' => 42], 'product');
> ```

```
  // this return the previous rememberd url 
  yii\helpers\Url::previous();
```

see this guide http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-url.html#remember-urls

and this for reference http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-url.html

Comment: I need previous controller or action id without remembering. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
```

This should redirect you to the last visited controller or action.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple in Yii2, you have to do this in your controller if you want to go back:

```
return $this->goBack();
```

Here is the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#goBack()-detail)

If you want to Store the previous URL for further processing then you can do as mentioned by @scaisedge [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36734941/1929511)